# How to optimize this code? Any other way to perform this?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a user object. Each opportunity will be associated with 1 user.
if the user is deactivated the opportunity with StageName = 'Prospecting' should be assigned to the manager associated with that user.

I have written the code however I want to know where all places I can improve my code.

```
trigger UsersTrigger on Users__c (after update) {
    Map<Id, Users__c> rec = new Map<Id, Users__c>();
    List<Opportunity> opList;
    for(Users__c userRecord : trigger.new){
        if(!userRecord.active__c){
            rec.put(userRecord.Id, userRecord);
        }
    }
    
    if(!rec.isEmpty()){
        opList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity op : [select Users__c, Users__r.Id from opportunity where StageName = 'Prospecting' 
                              AND Users__c in :rec.keySet()])
        {
            op.Users__c = rec.get(op.Users__r.Id).Manager__c;
            opList.add(op);
        }
        
        update opList;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.account_owner_transfer.htm&type=5 is worth a read

Answer (score 4):

The first rule of optimization club is to say, "I want to optimize `<specific thing X>`".
The second rule of optimization club is to measure that thing before you make any changes.
If you can't define a thing you want to optimize, and/or can't measure the  current code's performance, then optimization isn't a thing you should be trying to do.

With that said, I don't really see anything here that could be optimized. You're already following most of the best practices:

- No queries/dml inside of loops (i.e. your code is bulkified)
- You're gathering data for your query via a loop *before the query*
- The `if(!rec.isEmpty()){` check isn't necessary, but it does potentially save you a query (and queries are a precious resource)
- You're using a Map to get the relevant `User` instead of having a nested loop with `if(opp.User__c == loopUser.Id)`

There are a few things that could be improved, but I don't think any of them would make a meaningful impact on performance.

- Prefer using the lookup field on an SObject rather than trying to traverse a relationship. E.g. use `opp.User__c` instead of `opp.User__r.Id`
- Make your variable names meaningful. `rec` is not a good name for a Map because

  - It's singular instead of plural (collections of things are generally plural)
  - It doesn't really tell you what it represents (you'll have to look at more code than you otherwise would need to once you forget about why you wrote your trigger like this 6+ months from now)
  - A better name for this would be `usersById`

Probably the biggest improvement that could be made here would be to use a Trigger Framework like [Kevin O'Hara's Trigger Framework](https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework) (no affiliation).

Keeping the logic outside of the trigger (with the trigger's only job being to get you into your framework of choice) has several benefits:

- It's easier to test
- It's easier to test *in isolation* (you don't need to do test setup so that all of the *other* parts of your trigger can also run without error)
- It's possible that you don't need to perform any DML/Queries in your test (which helps make them run really fast, and helps makes it possible for you to run tests in parallel when not doing a deployment)
- It makes it possible to re-use code

Once you get beyond that, you'd want to start looking into things like [the Selector pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_selector_l_principles), which is used to centralize queries and can make it possible to avoid all DML in tests (DML is one of the things that slows tests down).

If I were to be pressed to improve the code you have (ignoring the "keep triggers logic-free" advice), it'd end up looking like

```java
trigger UsersTrigger on Users__c (after update) {
    // Since you're using this for a single purpose, it's probably better
    //   to just store the info you need rather than needing to .get()
    //   then use dot-notation
    Map<Id, Id> managerIdByInactiveUserId = new Map<Id, Id>();
    // If you're going to declare a variable, it's generally better to initialize
    //   it right away so you don't need to worry about nulls
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(Users__c userRecord : trigger.new) {
        // Less indented code is generally easier to read
        // So instead of focusing on logic that happens when a user isn't active
        //   , consider going to the next iteration when a user is active
        // (i.e. fail first/fail fast)
        if(userRecord.active__c){ continue; }
        
        managerIdByInactiveUserId.put(userRecord.Id, userRecord.Manager__c);
    }
    
    // I'm not wild about this if(), but it can prevent a query from being run
    if(!rec.isEmpty()){
        for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Users__c FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Prospecting' 
                              AND Users__c IN :managerIdByInactiveUserId.keySet()]) {
            opp.Users__c = managerIdByInactiveUserId.get(op.Users__c);
            oppList.add(opp);
        }
        
        update oppList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A trigger runs for a change to any field of the SObject. So particularly for SObjects with many fields that change, it is worth checking that the specific field has changed. This is particulary important for triggers that do updates as it is easy to end up with triggers that kick off other triggers that kick off other triggers and so on.

A few other points/opinions:

- No point consuming a SOQL call when the collection is empty as no records will ever be returned so the empty check is worth doing for queries (but not for inserts/updates as they can be short circuited to do nothing within the API)
- I prefer the shorter array syntax `Opportunity[] updates = new Opportunity[] {};` to the list syntax `List<Opportunity> updates = new List<Opportunity>;` as it is less typing and matches the `[...]` used on SOQL
- A SOQL query can have many `where` terms and they are all important so don't have then out of sight beyond the right margin of most people's viewers/editors
- Capitalising parts of a SOQL query is rarely done consistently and is a weird hangover from the past
- While you can modify the queried records and pass those to the `update`, I find using a separate collection clearer (and a nod to [Command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)); also see **PhilW**'s important comment about the danger of concurrent update data loss when what is queried is also updated - a stronger reason to not do that

```
trigger UsersTrigger on Users__c (after update) {

    // Only process when Active__c goes from true to false
    Map<Id, Id> userToManager = Map<Id, Id>();
    for(Users__c user : Trigger.new){
        if (!user.Active__c) {
            Users__c old = Trigger.oldMap.get(user.Id);
            if (old.Active__c) {
                Id manager = user.Manager__c;
                if (manager != null) {
                    userToManager.put(user.Id, manager);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Avoid querying where no need
    if (userToManager.size() > 0) {
        Opportunity[] updates = new Opportunity[] {};
        for (Opportunity op : [
            select Id, Users__c
            from Opportunity
            where StageName = 'Prospecting'
            and Users__c in :userToManager.keySet()
        ]) {
            Id manager = userToManager.get(op.Users__c);
            updates.add(new Opportunity(
                Id = op.Id,
                Users__c = manager
            ));
        }
        update updates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone using the Illuminated Cloud IDE has access to preferred case matching for Apex and SOQL/SOSL so I entirely disagree with your comment about lack of consistency with case use in SOQL. The use of queried objects for update is more than just stylistically poor, this can result in concurrent update data loss for fields queried but not updated, when `FOR UPDATE` was not used on the original query.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, I'm fine with "if Illuminated Cloud IDE then consistency is not a problem" but there is the "else if VSCode" to consider. (I don't know but imagine that VSCode is used by more people.) But given keyword highlighting (blue in the above code) what is the uppercasing actually for? Is uppercase for keywords a common choice for modern programming languages?

Comment: @PhilW I added the concurrent update risk problem; not something I'd thought of so thank-you and an important thing for people to consider.

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of optimizations you can do to make this code more efficient.

First, avoid copying records from one list to another. If you have an appropriate list, you can do:

```
Opportunity[] records = [select ... from ...];
for(Opportunity record: records) {
  ...
}
update records;
```

Second, when you have an if statement, you can usually encode that into the database query for efficiency.

For example, your query can be filtered as:

```
WHERE Users__c = :Trigger.new and Users__r.Active__c = false
```

Yes, we're often told to avoid queries when we can, but that's an optimization you should look towards only if you're actually in a bind.

Here's the final rewrite that you could use to implement this business logic:

```
trigger UsersTrigger on Users__c (after update) {
    Opportunity[] records = [
        SELECT Users__r.Manager__c 
        FROM Opportunity 
        WHERE StageName = 'Prospecting' AND 
            Users__c = :Trigger.new AND 
            Users__r.Active__c = FALSE AND
            Users__r.Manager__r.Active__c = TRUE];
    for(Opportunity record: records) {
        record.Users__c = record.Users__r.Manager__c;
    }
    update records;
}
```

Comment: Your first point: as per my comment on Keith's answer, if you query without `FOR UPDATE` you open this up to introducing concurrent update problems if you query fields that are not then part of the update.

Comment: Stylistically, I would also use `Users__c IN :Trigger.new` to make it clear this is testing an array of options.

Comment: @PhilW (a) YAGNI. There's little indication that this project needs record locks. I'm not querying any fields on the opportunity, and I'm only updating one field. There's a small window for the wrong user to be set, but it's on the order of milliseconds. (b) I believe the code is clear from context. Trigger.new cannot be anything but a List, so I don't feel the need to be Captain Obvious about it.

Comment: Maybe. My point is a general one and since you provided a general first part illustrating this I feel it worth at least mentioning then saying why it is OK **in this case** to do what you have done.